# Azure Storage Explorer not Responding on HDIsight Node Container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using ASE to access my Azure Storage Accounts and it works great, but for some reason when I try to access my HDIsight cluster container (the one that has the same name as the HDIsight cluster), I get nothing, it seems to time out without a message. This is quite frustrating. A search turned up nothing so I suspect this is not usual behavior?

Any ideas about what I could do to fix this?

Here is a fiddler screen shot. Looks like it transferred about 15+MB of data, but it never displayed it.... odd.

(note: I just noticed that it actually does work if I try and use ASE from a VM in the same data center as my storage account)

[image]

Comment: You could turn on Fiddler and see what exactly it is trying to do by tracing the request/response. May be add that to your question? HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the source code of Azure Storage Explorer (ASE) but from the Fiddler trace it seems that ASE is trying to fetch all blobs in your blob containers first and then displaying them in the UI (on the basis of multiple requests to your storage account and requests containing a continuation token as a query string parameter (`marker` parameter)) and it looks like you have lots of blobs in the container. Given that ASE makes use of .Net Storage Client Library, my guess is that it is using `ListBlobs` method which fetches all blobs in the container instead of `ListBlobsSegmented` method.

Your options would be:

- Get the source code of ASE from CodePlex and mess around with it and implement some kind of pagination.
- File a bug/feature request on ASE to support pagination.
- Use another Storage Explorer. If you're looking for desktop based blob explorer, I would recommend looking into Cerebrata tools ([www.cerebrata.com](http://www.cerebrata.com)). If you're looking for browser based tool, I would recommend looking at Cloud Portam ([www.cloudportam.com](http://www.cloudportam.com)) [Disclosure: I am developing Cloud Portam]